# How to populate new dataframe based on existing datarame in a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I want to make a new dataframe (b) by calculating the slope of multiple intervals over time. Below is a subset of the original data (a) and the code for generating the desired dataframe (b). I want to determine the slope of a$O2_229 and a$O2_Blank at intervals of a$RunTime 0.393-0.443, 0.000-0.042 and 0.042-0.093 respectively.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
a <- structure(list(RunTime = c(0, 0.042, 0.093, 0.143, 0.193, 0.243, 
0.293, 0.343, 0.393, 0.443, 0.493, 0.543, 0.593, 0.643, 0.693, 
0.743, 0.793, 0.842, 0.893, 0.943), O2_229 = c(223.479, 222.774, 
222.185, 221.557, 221.335, 220.879, 220.734, 220.396, 220.295, 
219.996, 219.859, 219.407, 219.33, 218.899, 218.725, 218.495, 
218.449, 217.833, 217.805, 217.856), O2_35 = c(189.719, 189.479, 
189.063, 188.843, 188.498, 188.237, 188.262, 187.959, 187.856, 
187.786, 187.512, 187.086, 186.957, 186.874, 186.589, 186.559, 
186.312, 186.267, 186.039, 185.947), O2_230 = c(189.894, 189.326, 
188.835, 188.786, 188.296, 188.064, 187.634, 187.417, 187.001, 
187.024, 186.684, 186.488, 186.162, 185.956, 185.931, 185.701, 
185.604, 185.491, 185.22, 185.384), O2_36 = c(191.005, 190.59, 
190.155, 189.836, 189.505, 189.103, 188.751, 188.343, 188.183, 
187.785, 187.563, 187.442, 186.949, 186.684, 186.486, 186.215, 
185.942, 185.858, 185.689, 185.567), O2_Blank = c(193.543, 193.315, 
192.927, 192.846, 192.373, 191.749, 191.284, 190.876, 190.44, 
190.196, 189.89, 189.381, 189.131, 188.841, 188.647, 188.631, 
188.315, 188.358, 188.062, 188.221)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class 
= "data.frame")

b <- data.frame("Light" = c("0%", "10%", "20%"),
            "229" = c((a$O2_229[a$RunTime == "0.443"] - 
a$O2_229[a$RunTime == "0.393"])/(0.443 - 0.393),
                      (a$O2_229[a$RunTime == "0.042"] - 
a$O2_229[a$RunTime == "0"])/(0.042 - 0),
                      (a$O2_229[a$RunTime == "0.093"] - 
a$O2_229[a$RunTime == "0.042"])/(0.093 - 0.042)),
            "Blank" = c((a$O2_Blank[a$RunTime == "0.443"] - 
a$O2_Blank[a$RunTime == "0.393"])/(102.643 - 92.043),
                      (a$O2_Blank[a$RunTime == "0.042"] - 
a$O2_Blank[a$RunTime == "0"])/(0.042 - 0),
                      (a$O2_Blank[a$RunTime == "0.093"] - 
a$O2_Blank[a$RunTime == "0.042"])/(0.093 - 0.042)))
```

The desired output is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Light 229           Blank
0%    -0.02820755   -0.02301887
10%   -16.78571429  -5.42857143
20%   -11.54901961  -7.60784314
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how you are summarizing, but ... `RunTime ==  "0.443"` is broken in at least two ways. Since those values are really `numeric`, you really cannot rely on tests of equality to match specific values, instead look for (perhaps) absolute difference within tolerance (e.g., `abs(RunTime - 0.443) < 1e-8`). (Why? See [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and perhaps google IEEE-754. It's a floating-point issue that plagues all programming languages.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I suppose a better way of explaining this would be: I want to determine the slope for each runtime interval (light %). So, what is the slope of o2_229 at light 10% (runtime 0-0.042) and so on for each intensity.

Comment: what is your expected output? Please try to clarify the question, as it is still very obscure what you want to achieve...

Comment: You're missing `a <- structure(list(RunTime = ...`

Comment: Edited - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you explain how the values are calculated in desired output ? How do you get `-0.02820755` and `-0.02301887`  from `a` ?

Comment: (a$O2_229[a$RunTime == "0.443"] - 
a$O2_229[a$RunTime == "0.393"])/(0.443 - 0.393) = -0.02820755

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure I'm missing something re: these light percentages - why you're using those values to calculate the 0% line is a mystery to me - but I think this is the scalable strategy you want to use, either way:

```r
  library(scales) # For percent()
  library(tidyverse)
  library(magrittr) # For pipe aliases like divide_by()
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'magrittr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     set_names
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     extract

a <- structure(list(RunTime = c(0, 0.042, 0.093, 0.143, 0.193, 0.243, 
                                0.293, 0.343, 0.393, 0.443, 0.493, 0.543, 0.593, 0.643, 0.693, 
                                0.743, 0.793, 0.842, 0.893, 0.943), 
                    O2_229 = c(223.479, 222.774, 
                               222.185, 221.557, 221.335, 220.879, 220.734, 220.396, 220.295, 
                               219.996, 219.859, 219.407, 219.33, 218.899, 218.725, 218.495, 
                               218.449, 217.833, 217.805, 217.856), 
                    O2_35 = c(189.719, 189.479, 
                              189.063, 188.843, 188.498, 188.237, 188.262, 187.959, 187.856, 
                              187.786, 187.512, 187.086, 186.957, 186.874, 186.589, 186.559, 
                              186.312, 186.267, 186.039, 185.947), 
                    O2_230 = c(189.894, 189.326, 
                               188.835, 188.786, 188.296, 188.064, 187.634, 187.417, 187.001, 
                               187.024, 186.684, 186.488, 186.162, 185.956, 185.931, 185.701, 
                               185.604, 185.491, 185.22, 185.384), 
                    O2_36 = c(191.005, 190.59, 
                              190.155, 189.836, 189.505, 189.103, 188.751, 188.343, 188.183, 
                              187.785, 187.563, 187.442, 186.949, 186.684, 186.486, 186.215, 
                              185.942, 185.858, 185.689, 185.567), 
                    O2_Blank = c(193.543, 193.315, 
                                 192.927, 192.846, 192.373, 191.749, 191.284, 190.876, 190.44, 
                                 190.196, 189.89, 189.381, 189.131, 188.841, 188.647, 188.631, 
                                 188.315, 188.358, 188.062, 188.221)), 
               row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

b <- a %>% 
  # Pre-compute this so it's no recomputed when each mutated variable uses it
  mutate(RunTimeDiff = diff(RunTime) %>% prepend(NA)) %>% 
  # Apply this slope-getting(?) function to each variable except RunTime and
  # its diff. var., which are dropped from the finished product
  transmute_at(vars(-RunTime, -RunTimeDiff), ~ {
    diff(.x) %>% 
      prepend(NA) %>% 
      divide_by(RunTimeDiff)
  }) %>% 
  # Drop all the O2_ prefixes, where present
  rename_all(str_remove, "O2_") %>% 
  # Build the Light percentage variable off the row numbers; row names are used
  # just because they get added to the left, where we want Light to be
  rownames_to_column("Light") %>% 
  mutate_at("Light", ~ {
    .x %>% as.numeric() %>% 
      subtract(1) %>% 
      divide_by(10) %>% 
      percent()
  })

b %>% as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 20 x 6
#>    Light   `229`   `35`   `230`  `36`   Blank
#>    <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 0%     NA     NA      NA     NA     NA    
#>  2 10%   -16.8   -5.71  -13.5   -9.88  -5.43 
#>  3 20%   -11.5   -8.16   -9.63  -8.53  -7.61 
#>  4 30%   -12.6   -4.40   -0.98  -6.38  -1.62 
#>  5 40%    -4.44  -6.90   -9.8   -6.62  -9.46 
#>  6 50%    -9.12  -5.22   -4.64  -8.04 -12.5  
#>  7 60%    -2.90   0.5    -8.6   -7.04  -9.3  
#>  8 70%    -6.76  -6.06   -4.34  -8.16  -8.16 
#>  9 80%    -2.02  -2.06   -8.32  -3.20  -8.72 
#> 10 90%    -5.98  -1.40    0.460 -7.96  -4.88 
#> 11 100%   -2.74  -5.48   -6.8   -4.44  -6.12 
#> 12 110%   -9.04  -8.52   -3.92  -2.42 -10.2  
#> 13 120%   -1.54  -2.58   -6.52  -9.86  -5.   
#> 14 130%   -8.62  -1.66   -4.12  -5.3   -5.80 
#> 15 140%   -3.48  -5.70   -0.500 -3.96  -3.88 
#> 16 150%   -4.60  -0.6    -4.6   -5.42  -0.320
#> 17 160%   -0.920 -4.94   -1.94  -5.46  -6.32 
#> 18 170%  -12.6   -0.918  -2.31  -1.71   0.878
#> 19 180%   -0.549 -4.47   -5.31  -3.31  -5.80 
#> 20 190%    1.02  -1.84    3.28  -2.44   3.18
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

That'd be the pure tidyverse approach, at least.

Comment: Thanks - how would this apply when the RunTime intervals are different lengths? I didn't include this in the example for simplicity but I have some light % that are longer than others. 0% values are because lights were turned off at the very end. i.e. each intensity is not the same RunTime duration

Comment: Different interval sizes should be handled appropriately this way, so long as the rows are ordered right. The differences from row to row w.r.t. each var. will get divided by the row's difference w.r.t. runtime. A specific relationship between RunTime, or at least row number, and the light % would help, though. Not sure if this +10% each time is appropriate.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the help - new to tidyverse. 0% = 0.000-0.042, 10% = 0.042-0.093, 20% = 0.093-0.193, 30% = 0.193-0.293, 40% = 0.293-0.343, 50% = 0.343-0.443, 60% = 0.443-0.593, 70% = 0.593-0.743, 80% = 0.743-0.943. So they're all different.